# How to use shared memory in python multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

This is a demo of computing cross-correlation between each two signals. I wrote the code below, but the memory usage of that with shared memory is the same as that without the shared memory. In addition, the elapsed time of that with shared memory is much more. Could anyone point out where is the problem?

```py
from multiprocessing.shared_memory import SharedMemory
from multiprocessing.managers import SharedMemoryManager
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed
from multiprocessing import current_process, cpu_count, Process, Pool
import multiprocessing as mp
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tracemalloc
import time
from functools import partial
import itertools


def generate_tasks(keys):
    tasks = []
    for ns1, ns2 in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(keys, 2):
        if ns1 == ns2:
            continue
        tasks.append([ns1, ns2])
    return tasks


def work_with_shared_memory(shm_name, shape, dtype, task):
    ns1, ns2 = task
    # print(f'With SharedMemory: {current_process()=}')
    # Locate the shared memory by its name
    shm = SharedMemory(shm_name)
    # Create the np.recarray from the buffer of the shared memory
    np_array = np.recarray(shape=shape, dtype=dtype, buf=shm.buf)
    return np_array[ns1] * np_array[ns2]


def work_no_shared_memory(np_array: np.recarray, task):
    ns1, ns2 = task
    # print(f'No SharedMemory: {current_process()=}')
    # Without shared memory, the np_array is copied into the child process
    return np_array[ns1] * np_array[ns2]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create cc data
    nsta = 200
    nfft = 5000
    d = dict([(str(i), np.random.rand(nfft)) for i in range(nsta)])
    tasks = generate_tasks(d.keys())
    print(f"number of task: {len(tasks)}")
    df = pd.DataFrame(d)

    # Convert into numpy recarray to preserve the dtypes
    np_array = df.to_records(index=False)
    del df
    shape, dtype = np_array.shape, np_array.dtype
    print(f"np_array's size={np_array.nbytes/1e6}MB")

    # Without shared memory
    tracemalloc.start()
    start_time = time.time()
    do_work = partial(work_no_shared_memory, np_array)
    with Pool(cpu_count()) as pool:
        fs = pool.map(do_work, tasks)
    # Check memory usage
    current, peak = tracemalloc.get_traced_memory()
    print(f"Current memory usage {current/1e6}MB; Peak: {peak/1e6}MB")
    print(f'Time elapsed: {time.time()-start_time:.2f}s')
    tracemalloc.stop()

    # With shared memory
    # Start tracking memory usage
    tracemalloc.start()
    start_time = time.time()
    with SharedMemoryManager() as smm:
        # Create a shared memory of size np_arry.nbytes
        shm = smm.SharedMemory(np_array.nbytes)
        # Create a np.recarray using the buffer of shm
        shm_np_array = np.recarray(shape=shape, dtype=dtype, buf=shm.buf)
        # Copy the data into the shared memory
        np.copyto(shm_np_array, np_array)

        do_work = partial(work_with_shared_memory, shm.name, shape, dtype)
        with mp.Pool(cpu_count()) as pool:
            fs = pool.map(do_work, tasks)

    # Check memory usage
    current, peak = tracemalloc.get_traced_memory()
    print(f"Current memory usage {current/1e6}MB; Peak: {peak/1e6}MB")
    print(f'Time elapsed: {time.time()-start_time:.2f}s')
    tracemalloc.stop()
```

The output is:

```
number of task: 19900
np_array's size=8.0MB
Current memory usage 799.162859MB; Peak: 825.615495MB
Time elapsed: 3.77s
Current memory usage 798.792452MB; Peak: 825.256245MB
Time elapsed: 13.54s
```